# understanding c++, compilation etc

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Do you know a good, concise (not a book, possibly free documentation) reference that explains the basics of how a c++ compiler works? I think it'd be beneficial for better understanding some rules of c++ programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GCC Internals](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_C_Compiler_Internals) free ebook.

> The purpose of this book is to address
>   the demands of GCC hackers. We start
>   with a description of GCC 3.4.1
>   architecture focusing on the source
>   code parser. We chose this version of
>   GCC because we used this version
>   mostly. Then we address the problem of
>   extension development. We present the
>   GCC Extensibility Modules (GEM)
>   project in the next chapter. GEM
>   provides a number of hooks throughout
>   GCC source code. It is implemented as
>   a patch to GCC. A GEM-based compiler
>   extension is developed as a
>   stand-alone program. When the
>   extension is completed, only its
>   source code is distributed compared
>   with distributing the source code of
>   the GCC if GEM is not used. We give
>   examples that demonstrate GEM
>   programming at the end of the book.

(EDIT: Sorry, I missed you don't want a book. But I still think this is great resource of information you are looking for. You certainly don't need to read it as a whole, you can go only through the sections you are interested in.)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this university site](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) which explains the steps of the compilation process.  It covers how to compile your code into an executable, a shared library, or a dynamically linked library using GCC.  It also covers how the compiler knows where to look for header files and libraries, and other topics.